# Download doesn't work on web page being imported to mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, vue.js, download

We have a web page build using vuejs and also a mobile application(android/IOS). what we do is import the web page to the app  and it will serve as a content. My problem is when I tried to download a QR code, it work on browser but not when it is imported.

Hope you help me.

thanks.

Comment: There isn't enough information here. Use [Chrome Remote Debugging on WebView](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews) and see if you can find and fix your issue.

Comment: `but not when it is imported.` how exactly is it *imported*?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I mean, the download doesn't work, when the web page is in the mobile app

Comment: ok, but that does not explain `how exactly is it imported?` what does `imported` mean? Show the code.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko sorry I dont have the code for the mobile app.. but its like using an iframe tag in html